# Can this argument in the calculation of $P(X+Y<a)$ be made rigorous?

Tags: probability

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independant real random variables. Let's try to work out the cumulative distribution function $P(X+Y<a)$ in terms of the CDFs of $X$ and $Y$.

Well, if $X=x$, then in some sense we should have $P(X+Y<a)=P(Y<a+x)$. We can try to sum over all values of $x$ in a kind of continuous analogue of the [total probability formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability):

$$\begin{align}P(X+Y<a)&\stackrel ? = \int_\mathbb R P(X=x)P(X+Y<a\mid X=x)\\
&=\int_\mathbb R P(X=x)P(Y<a+x)\ dx
\end{align}$$

So, if $X$ has a density $d_X(x)$ and $Y$ has a CDF $F_Y(x)$, we should have:

$$\int_\mathbb R d_X(x) F_Y(a+x)\ dx$$

Can this be made rigorous? What's the most general possible formulation of this "continuous law of total probability", for instance, how could we state it without assuming $X$ has a density?

Comment: The CDF of $X+Y$ is function $a\mapsto P(X+Y\leq a)$ (not $a\mapsto P(X+Y< a)$). If $X=x$ then $X+Y\leq a\iff Y\leq a-x$ (not $Y\leq a+x$). If $X$ has continuous distribution then $P(X=x)=0$ for each $x$ so that the integrand on RHS is the zero-function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent then:

$$P\left(X+Y\leq a\right)=\int\int1_{\left(-\infty,a\right]}\left(x+y\right)dF_Y\left(y\right)dF_X\left(x\right)=$$$$\int\int1_{\left(-\infty,a-x\right]}\left(y\right)dF_Y\left(y\right)dF_X\left(x\right)=\int F_{Y}\left(a-x\right)dF_X\left(x\right)$$

If $f_{X}$ is a density for the distribution of $X$ then RHS equals
$\int F_{Y}\left(a-x\right)f_{X}\left(x\right)dx$

Comment: Could you provide some more details? I think step two is just a standard change of variables, but what exactly are you doing in steps 1 and 3? What definitions/results are you using to expand the probability as a double integral, and to collapse the double integral back into a single integral?

Comment: Step 3: do you understand that $\mathbb E1_A(X)=P(X\in A)$ where $1_A$ denotes the characteristic function that corresponds with measurable set $A$? Note that $\int1_{\left(-\infty,a-x\right]}\left(y\right)dF\left(y\right)$
can be recognized as $\mathbb{E}1_{\left(-\infty,a-x\right]}\left(Y\right)=P\left\{ Y\in\left(-\infty,a-x\right]\right\} =F_{Y}\left(a-x\right)$.

Comment: Step 1): In general $\mathbb{E}g\left(X,Y\right)=\int g\left(x,y\right)dF_{X,Y}\left(x,y\right)$
where $F_{X,Y}$ is a distribution function on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.
If $X,Y$ are independent then $F_{X,Y}\left(x,y\right)=F_{X}\left(x\right)F_{Y}\left(y\right)$
and $\int g\left(x,y\right)dF_{X,Y}\left(x,y\right)=\int\int g\left(x,y\right)dF_{X}\left(x\right)F_{Y}\left(y\right)=\int\int g\left(x,y\right)dF_{Y}\left(y\right)F_{X}\left(x\right)$.